# float32 vs. float64 python checking equality

Tags: python, binary, precision

In the below code, checking equality between float64 fails due to binary representation issue, as I would expect. However, I don't understand why float32 as no problem with this. My understanding is that it should be susceptable to the same binary representation issues, and has precision much lower than 0.0003. Why do the below equality checks pass for float32?

```
import numpy as np

x = np.float64(0.0003)      # 0.003
y = np.float64(0.0001 * 3)  # 0.00030000000000000003
assert x == y  # fail

x = x.astype(np.float32)    # 0.0003
y = y.astype(np.float32)    # 0.0003
assert x == y  # okay

x = np.float32(0.0003)      # 0.003
y = np.float32(0.0001 * 3)   # 0.003
assert x == y  # okay
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you're familiar with the problems of binary floating point accuracy, but anybody who isn't should read [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/5987)

Converting from a type with high accuracy to one with lower accuracy involves rounding.  The rules for rounding binary floating point are well established, and always try to deliver the closest representable value to the one you started with.  It's quite easy for two 64-bit values to round to the same 32-bit value, because the intervals between consecutive values are so much wider.

For your examples you can see that they're ever so slightly different, one is too low and the other is too high.  But look at how close they are!

```
>>> x = np.float64(0.0003)
>>> y = np.float64(0.0001 * 3)
>>> f'{x:.65f}'
'0.00029999999999999997371893933895137251965934410691261291503906250'
>>> f'{y:.65f}'
'0.00030000000000000002792904796322659422003198415040969848632812500'
```

When you round them to float32 they become identical because of the necessary rounding applied.

```
>>> x = x.astype(np.float32)
>>> f'{x:.65f}'
'0.00030000001424923539161682128906250000000000000000000000000000000'
>>> y = y.astype(np.float32)
>>> f'{y:.65f}'
'0.00030000001424923539161682128906250000000000000000000000000000000'
```

When you see the closest alternatives they could have chosen, it's easy to see why they rounded the way they did.

```
>>> one = np.float32(1.0)
>>> f'{np.nextafter(x, one):.65f}'
'0.00030000004335306584835052490234375000000000000000000000000000000'
>>> f'{np.nextafter(x, -one):.65f}'
'0.00029999998514540493488311767578125000000000000000000000000000000'
```

Answer (score 2):

Imagine your two friends ran a marathon in actual times 5:04:16 and 4:58:47. You ask them about their times.

Float64-minded friends might tell you "5 hours 4 minutes" and "4 hours 59 minutes". Not exact, but pretty exact. You conclude they're ***not*** equally fast.

Float32-minded friends might tell you "5 hours" and "5 hours". Even less exact. You conclude they ***are*** equally fast.